# Firebase Custom Domain Hosting - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, domain-name

#### Problem

I want to set up a website (example.com) and host it with Firebase.

#### What I Have Done so Far

- Look at [Firebase Custom Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811162/firebase-custom-domain-name)
- Acquired example.com
- Uploaded website to example.firebaseapp.com
- Verified ownership of example.com
- Added A records to DNS records (I am using domain.com as the registrar)
- Connected custom domain (example.com) through the Firebase Console
- Waited for changes to propagate

#### What Is Currently Happening

- My website is uploaded to example.firebaseapp.com (this is good). I also want the same content to be shown on example.com
- When I access https://example.com on my **phone not connected to wifi**, using chrome, everything works as expected. I see the same content as on example.firebaseapp.com.
- When I access https://example.com from **phone connected to wifi** or **my computer** I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. This error occurs for me on Chrome (normal and incognito mode) and Edge (normal and InPrivate mode)
- When I access http://example.com from **my computer** I the parked domain page. I also tried this from Chrome (normal & incognito) and Edge (normal and InPrivate)

#### What Are My Questions?

1. How do I get https://example.com to show the same content as example.firebaseapp.com and not give a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
2. How do I get http://example.com to show the same content as example.firebaseapp.com instead of the parked domain page?

Comment: If you hadn't chosen to hide the information _you're asking for help to *publish*_, someone might be able to look at your setup and see what's wrong. But since you did make that choice, all you can get is wild guesses.

Comment: What information are you looking for?

Comment: @alexdriedger what was the solution that helped you? I am getting the same error, while my website is working very well on some networks, while on others its showing `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Its hosted on firebase, and the certificate is also provided by firebase.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but only from certain networks.  When connected to wifi at the coffee shop, the .web.app domain works, but the custom one does not.  When I change to my phone hotspot, both work.